# git stash apply unknown option: -encodedCommand error

Tags: git, powershell, git-stash, posh-git

When applying a git stash with the command:

`git stash apply stash@{1}`

As suggested in the [documentation on git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing).

I receive the error:

```
unknown option: -encodedCommand error
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What I didn't realise...

I was in powershell (to use [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)) and of course {} is indicating powershell code.

Therefore surrounding in '' will ensure powershell interprets it as a string.

```
git stash apply 'stash@{1}'
```

Notably posh-git autocompletes the name when pressing tab (which made me realise my error).

Answer (score 2):

*Putting this here for Google searches:*

This will also happen if you are using a **Windows runner** with **GitHub Actions** and miss the `$` in an expression like `${{ github.ref }}`.

---

What makes this especially confusing in this case, is that the error will be interleaved with the output, making it *appear* to come from whatever you're invoking. E.g. in my case:

```
Run iscc.exe InstallCreation\inno\service.iss /DMyAppVersion={{ github.ref }}
  iscc.exe InstallCreation\inno\service.iss /DMyAppVersion={{ github.ref }}
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
Unknown option: -encodedCommand
Inno Setup 6 Command-Line Compiler
```

⬆️the `-encodedCommand` has **nothing** to do with `Inno Setup 6`.

Comment: Thanks for contributing davetapley!